# What’s an efficient way to take multiple items out of a Redis set or list, guaranteeing the number received

Tags: redis

I have list (it can be a set if that’s the only way). I have a number of clients connected, the list will be being filled up externally one at a time.

I need an efficient way to take *N* items out of that list, as a batch, into one client. I don’t care which client it ends up on, just that the first *N* items pushed into the list end up with one client, and the next *N* may end up on another (or the same).

I’m really not sure how I could achieved this with lists, I can block for pop but only one at a time. I’d really prefer the ordering from lists.

I was thinking I could use sets, have all clients hitting Redis with SCARD. When they detect the count is =>, SPOP for N. That should get me at least one client filled with N, and every client that receives fewer than N returns them back to the set.

The fact I’m repeating the SCARD feels really bad, and passing things back in unreliable.

Is there anything more baked in to support this sort of flow, or a cleaner algorithm (that ideally has a list?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the logic into a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval), to make sure the client gets `N` sequential items.

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local N = tonumber(ARGV[1])

local size = redis.call("llen", key)

if size < N then return {} end    -- ensure that there're at least N items

local res = {}
for i = 1, N do                   -- get N items in a transaction
    res[i] = redis.call("lpop", key);
end

return res
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn’t thought of that. Is there any way to do this without having all my clients sending this repeatedly? I’m ok with sending this, sleeping, repeating, but if there’s a way to reduce round trips that would be ideal

Comment: Yes, but you have to do more complicated work. Let's call the list as `target list`. All clients call `BLPOP` to block on another list, say, `notification list`. One client, say, `watcher client`, subscribes the [key space notification](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) to check if someone pushes an item to the `target list`. If there's a new item, the `watcher client` pushes a notification to `notification list`. So that one of your client will wake up and run the Lua script.

Comment: Thanks. That's very useful!

Comment: I upvoted this answer - @for_stack you know my weaknesses, arrrgh!