# Redis BRPOP and ZADD atomically

Tags: ruby, lua, redis, atomic

I need to `BRPOP` and then add the popped value to a sorted set with `ZADD`. I see two solutions to this (I am using Ruby):

1. Write a Lua script that performs these two operations. However, Lua scripts cannot block, since they will hold down the whole server in the meantime. So this solution does not work;
2. Use `redis-rb`'s `multi { ... }` block. However, here I cannot use the popped value in the `ZADD` command, since this is not the way `redis-rb` implements this block.

With these, I am left only with a non-atomic way to achieve this, that is, use `redis-rb` to sequentially trigger these commands. However, I really need atomicity here. What would be the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR impossible is possible.

You can, if you're not hung on poppin' from Lists, check out both my new module as well as the shiny new pull request to Redis core.

1. Ze POP Module: https://github.com/itamarhaber/zpop
2. Pull request #4879 "Implements [B]Z[REV]POP and the respective unit tests": https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/4879

Comment: Redis Module seems more powerful than scripting. I should update my knowledge on Redis Module :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am stuck to lists, and also, as mentioned before, I would like to rely only on standard Redis, since I am building a library that should be easily pluggable into any application.

Comment: @for_stack modules are *much more powerful*, but Lua is simpler and more accessible (i.e. not every developer can develop in C a Redis Module). But OTO modules are so much fun - if you need help any help, you know how to get me ;)

Comment: @linkyndy gotcha. So, once ZPOP becomes standard Redis you'll be able to use it. That said, it may be worthwhile thinking about augmenting ZPOP with the ability to pop from lists and push into a sorted set, as well as something like `BZPOPZADD`.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap `RPOP` and `ZADD` in a Lua script, e.g. `RPOPZADD`, to run them atomically, and do some work on the client side to simulate a blocking behavior.

The following is the pseudo code:

```
while (true) {
    bool ret = redis.eval(RPOPZADD);    // return immediately
    if (!ret) {
        // No item in the list, wait for a while
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would rather use a more robust solution that relies on existing features, than bake an in-house method. I still hope one exists and I am missing it...

Comment: If you don't want to run the loop on the client side, you can try a more complicated method with the key space notification feature. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933661/what-s-an-efficient-way-to-take-multiple-items-out-of-a-redis-set-or-list-guara/49935299?noredirect=1#comment86905474_49935299) on another similar question for details.

Comment: This looks promising, but I am developing a tool that should be plug-and-play, so tweaking the Redis setup isn't a direction I am keen to follow. Also, this greatly complicates things, which I wouldn't necessarily.

Comment: Upvoted  this one too, naturally, but added my own as well.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify the reason you need a sorted set, if you can work around it and use a list instead you can use `BRPOPLPUSH` the atomicly move the element to a different list, and sort it later in a non atomic manner.

Another option is to write a Redis Module that will do that for you - [modules blocking ops](https://redis.io/topics/modules-blocking-ops)

Comment: I need a sorted set because I need to pop an element and add it to a place where I can store also the current time, together with the added element. I would've really liked to use `BRPOPLPUSH`, but I can't in these circumstances. Regarding modules...that will be highly depenent on the Redis installation, which would stand in the way of my tool's portability and simplicity.

Comment: @linkyndy sounds like you add them already in order. If it is only timestamp why not just append or prepend to the data string?

Comment: Because I need the timestamp of when the `BRPOPLPUSH` was performed. The only place where I can do this would be the destination of `BRPOPLPUSH`, but that would unnecessarily create too many separate keys that would need to be handled after.

Comment: @linkyndy in that case, break it to 3 operations. Pop, prepend TS, and push. Load it as a lua for atomicity and server side computation offload. (you'll have to bring the TS from home, or use replicate effects to use the TIME command)

Comment: @OfirLuzon though you was my pal... IQ and all... check out my answer about using a module and the new PR I made

Comment: @OfirLuzon I also need the blocking part, which I don't really want to manually handle on the client.